# Issue on Getting Custom post type Thumbnail's URL

Tags: theme-development, permalinks, post-thumbnails

I need to get the URL for Custom post type Thumbnail and assign it to

```
the_post_thumbnail('', array('class' => 'group1 img-responsive',
                             'href' =>get_permalink($thumbnail->ID)));
```

at this code

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'sunglassesCPT', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
$meta = get_post_custom($post->ID);
   echo '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">';
echo '<div class="thumbnail text-center">';
the_post_thumbnail('', array('class' => 'group1 img-responsive', 'href' =>get_permalink($thumbnail->ID)));
echo '<div class="caption">';
echo '<h4 class="product-title">'.the_title().'</h4>';
echo '<div class="ptitle"><p class="price">'.$meta['my_meta_box_text'][0]. '</p></div>';
echo '<p><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-brown" role="button">Quick View</a></p>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
endwhile;
?>
```

but this not linking to the image. Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `href` attribute you are passing under `the_post_thumbnail()` is incorrect. Note that this attribute is applied to the `img` tag which obviously doesn't supports `href` attribute.

It would be better to wrap `the_post_thumbnail()` with an `<a>` tag. So it will look something like the following:

```
echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $thumbnail->ID ) . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail', array( 'class' => 'group1 img-responsive' ) ) . '</a>';
```

Comment: Thanks Ram it was great help and hint. Can I also ask you to do me favor and take a look at this Post too? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166068/issue-on-counting-cpts-under-taxonomy-term

Comment: I am really stunned there!